# how to change value when bsdatepicker already changed the value

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

When I click a date with (ngx-bootstrap) bsdatepicker, I would like to change it back to the original date when it hits the else branch of the function.

I seems simple but it seems like bsdatepicker only changes the date in the input field after all the parts of my function are already done.

Any tips, suggests, and/or answers are appreciated!

```js
onValueChange(event) {
  // console.log(`DatePicker ${event}`);
  if (this.canDeactivate()) {
    // let value: Date = event;
    this.selectDate = event;
    if (!!this.selectDate) {//this.selectDate !== undefined && this.selectDate !== null
      let dt: Date = this.selectDate;  //current date of week
      //this.serviceMonth = dt;
      let currentWeekDay = dt.getDay();
      this.wkStart = new Date(new Date(dt).setDate(dt.getDate() - currentWeekDay));
      this.wkEnd = new Date(new Date(this.wkStart).setDate(this.wkStart.getDate() + 6));
      console.log(this.wkStart + " - " + this.wkEnd);
      this.getWeeklyTito(this.wkStart, this.wkEnd);
    }
  } else {
    if (new Date(this.caseForm.controls.selectDatesFormControl.value).getTime() !== event.getTime()) {
      this.caseForm.patchValue({
        selectDatesFormControl: this.datePipe.transform(currDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
      })
    }
    this.dataTransferService.displayUnsaveMessage();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" #weeklyDatePicker class="form-control form-control-sm"
formControlName="selectDatesFormControl" bsDatepicker [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate="maxDate"
[bsConfig]="{ showWeekNumbers : false,  selectFromOtherMonth: true }"
(bsValueChange)="onValueChange($event)" onkeydown="return false" >
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @dantey89 yes, but it's a temporary patch. If you have any tips/solutions I'm listening